# error on google app engine with laravel

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel

I've tried to deploy my laravel based projec to gae, but I'm getting a blank screen and this in the error logs

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_get_contents(/base/data/home/apps/s~random-gae-name/1.380824294377640683/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/resources/plain.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /base/data/home/apps/s~random-gae-name/1.380824294377640683/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/PlainDisplayer.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'file_get_conten...', '/base/data/home...', 21, Array)
#1 /base/data/home/apps/s~random-gae-name/1.380824294377640683/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/PlainDisplayer.php(21): file_get_contents('/base/data/home...')
#2 /base/data/home/apps/s~random-gae-name/1.380824294377640683/bootstrap/compiled.php(9292): Illuminate\Exception\PlainDisplayer->display(Object(ErrorException))
#3 /base/data/home/apps/s~random-gae-name/1.380824294377640683/bootstrap/compiled.php(9244): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->displayException(Object( in /base/data/home/apps/s~random-gae-name/1.380824294377640683/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/PlainDisplayer.php on line 21
```

I don't know what this means.

My php.ini

```
; enable function that are disabled by default in the App Engine PHP runtime
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, php_uname, getmypid"

; Cloud storage buckets that Laravel needs to include files from. By default
; in production the first bucket declared here will be used for app storage.
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "x"

allow_url_include=1
```

and my yaml file

```
application: x
module: default
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: public/index.php


- url: /(.*\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|css|js|html|txt|pdf|mp3|eps|svg|ttf|woff|eot))
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: (.*\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|css|js|html|txt|pdf|mp3|eps|svg|ttf|woff|eot))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need to change the storage path to your bucket. App Engine apps can't write to the local file system, so you have to override Laravel's Application class method `bindInstallPaths` to allow the use of Google Cloud Storage as `app/storage/` directory.

Use an inherited class of `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` and then override `bindInstallPaths` method.

```
// MyApplicationClass.php file 
class MyApplicationClass extends Illuminate\Foundation\Application 
{
    public function bindInstallPaths(array $paths)
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ID']) && !empty($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ID'])) { 
            if (realpath($paths['app'])) {
                $this->instance('path', realpath($paths['app']));
            }
            elseif (file_exists($paths['app'])) {
                $this->instance('path', $paths['app']);
            }
            else {
                $this->instance('path', FALSE);
            }

            foreach (array_except($paths, array('app')) as $key => $value)
            {
                if (realpath($value)) {
                    $this->instance("path.{$key}", realpath($value));
                }
                elseif (file_exists($value)) {
                    $this->instance("path.{$key}", $value);
                }
                else {
                    $this->instance("path.{$key}", FALSE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            parent::{__FUNCTION__}($paths);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this class in `bootstrap/start.php` instead of original one.

```
$app = (isset($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ID']) && !empty($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ID'])) 
        ? new MyApplicationClass
        : new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
```

And finally, you have to change the storage path in your `paths.php` file

```
// paths.php file 
$storage_path = (isset($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ID']) && !empty($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ID'])) 
                    ? "gs://" . $your_bucket_name . "/storage"
                    : __DIR__.'/../app/storage';
mkdir($storage_path); 

return array (
    ...
    'storage' => $storage_path,
);
```

I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Where does MyApplicationClass.php go?

Comment: I've got it in my own application namespace, but I think that you can put it in some autoload directory. It depends of your `composer.json` file. You can add a "app/lib" entry in the `classmap` section and set it there. Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` after do it.